# formula field on master record that displays a text field on the max child record

Tags: formula, master-detail

I have a custom object, **Recoveries Placement**, related to the **Case** object in a master-detail relationship.

I need to surface a text field from the MAX **Recoveries Placement** record on the **Case** layout. Obviously, I cannot create a roll-up for a text field nor can I create a downward formula field.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this declaratively or will I need to forward to dev for Apex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't *really* do it declaratively. You could kind of do it with some complex Flows, but since Flow cannot respond to delete events, it'll never be perfect.

You can do it with [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries), though. You'd create a rollup from Recoveries Placement to Case, with the rollup operation MAX, sorted by whichever field you prefer, and rolling up the field Id. The rollup would target a lookup field from Case->Recoveries Placement, so it would maintain that relationship to the desired Recoveries Placement record.

You'd then be able to write formula fields against that relationship.